# iTextSharp: impossible to create PDF. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm trying to convert an HTML to a PDF using iTextSharp. 
This is my function:

```
 public static Byte[] ConvertToPdf_iTextSharp(string html)
    {
        Byte[] res;

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(html);

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();

            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            res = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();                
        }

        return res;
    }
```

I got an error on  `HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);`

Error is: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I found that the problem is when there are images in my HTML.

Images are standard html tag `<img src="http://mywebsite/images/some.png" />`

I found that if i "force" local path name ( something like this `<img src="c:/inetpub/wwwroot/mysite/images/some.png" />`)  it works.

What can it be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the images on a website you need to login to access?  When you access them through your browser, you have cookies with your auth info stored.  When you access them through your iTextSharp you don't.

Comment: Images are on the same webserver

Comment: I don't understand how that answers my question.  If you open a new incognito window and try to access the images, does it let you or do you need to login?

Comment: I solved thanks to your previous question: problem was an authentication problem. I moved images under another site (with anonymous access enabled) and now it works all well... thanks

Comment: Glad to help.  I added the comment as an answer to your question.  If it helped you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an authentication problem.  Can you verify that the images are hosted on a website that doesn't require you to login?  The easiest way to check is to open a new incognito window and try to access an image.  If you get a access denied page, you know the problem.

To fix it, either move the images to a site that doesn't require authentication or setup iTextSharp with your login credentials to the site.